# Insert bcrypt hash into specific line in file using bash

Tags: bash, file, insert, bcrypt

I need to update an application configuration by inserting bcrypt hash into file `config.yml` at specific lines.

```
echo -e "$Enter password for user1"
read -p ": " user1_pass

echo -e "$Enter password for user2"
read -p ": " user2_pass

user1_hash=$(htpasswd -bnBC 10 "" $user1_pass | tr -d ':\n')
user2_hash=$(htpasswd -bnBC 10 "" $user2_pass | tr -d ':\n')
```

`$user1_hash` should be placed inline 2 and `$user2_hash` inline 7.

config.yml

```
    user1:
      hash: "$2y$12$shEKzuVfogdZFbbraSqhwOOh96hfxe1NzLQbpmHJvgDUeRfRrkf3a"
      reserved: "true"
      roles: "user"

    user2:
      hash: "$2y$12$Fkc5GAp9Za5caIfHjBgNQ.jNEss0SJfCLTlm9EhAcjzPVy.kLriBa"
      reserved: "true"
      roles: "user"
```

What is the best approach to do that using `bash`?

Comment: if you just want to insert a line in specific line, you can use sed -i '4i hash: $user1_hash' . It'll insert into line 4, in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the file using Ruby :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'yaml'
obj = YAML.load_file('config.yml')

bcrypt_hash='$2y$12$shEKzuVfogdZFbbraSqhwOOh96hfxe1NzLQbpmHJvgDUeRfRrkf3a' 
obj['user1']['hash'] = bcrypt_hash
obj['user2']['hash'] = bcrypt_hash

puts YAML.dump(obj)
```

This will output :

```
... More yml content
user1:
  hash: "$2y$12$shEKzuVfogdZFbbraSqhwOOh96hfxe1NzLQbpmHJvgDUeRfRrkf3a"
user2:
  hash: "$2y$12$shEKzuVfogdZFbbraSqhwOOh96hfxe1NzLQbpmHJvgDUeRfRrkf3a"
... More yml content
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It will remove other data related to ```user1``` and ```user2``` objects. Is it possible to make changes only in ```hash:```?

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyword `echo` to write into the file

```sh
echo -e "$Enter password for user1"
read -p ": " user1_pass

echo -e "$Enter password for user2"
read -p ": " user2_pass

user1_hash=$(htpasswd -bnBC 10 "" $user1_pass | tr -d ':\n')
user2_hash=$(htpasswd -bnBC 10 "" $user2_pass | tr -d ':\n')

echo "user1:" > config.yml
echo "    hash: " +  $user1_hash >> config.yml
echo "user2:" >> config.yml
echo "    hash: " + $user2_hash >> config.yml
```

the contents of `config.yml` file being

```
user1:
    hash:  + $2y$10$7S0fC4wTqAfm9ytJ5BquC.3KITsqLoqPXHyj3mzgXdvw10TRIybni
user2:
    hash:  + $2y$10$jcYMrOsdIzwR3AlSONNfCuc.B5AoGVV4i31KSsx0PLlpn17issJfe
```

Comment: yes, it's kind of solution, but I had other data in ```config.yml``` related to ```user1``` and ```user2```, which should be in their place. Update my description.

Comment: I have updated the code to overwrite the content every time the code is run